# How to make a JavaScript library which can work with Browser, NodeJS and Single Page Applications (React etc.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, single-page-application

**So what I want to ask is:** Is there a way to convert this simple file into a library which can work with Browsers (script tag), Node JS and Single Page Applications using single codebase?

Until now, all I have been doing was using libraries but it never came to my mind that it isn't actually that simple to make one. I am working on a React application where I created a simple helper file with exports. I thought "why not make it an independent library in NPM?". Just as I started testing it independently in NodeJS environment, I came to realize that there is actually a lot of difference in the way both environments make imports.

I have slight knowledge of Webpack, but I don't know how to approach it. Would I need different codes for different environments?

**Another thing that confused me** was when I thought about "How do we actually import things/functions from libraries?" Like when we install any library from NPM INSTALL and we do "import { abc } from 'library'", does it look for an index.js file in the library folder or what? Or in case of Node, "let lib = require('library')", where it does it look since its a different environment than SPA?

In conclusion, I have a simple single file I want to launch in NPM as a library which could work in any environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, so a very broad answer: Look at tools like [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/), [`rollup`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/), and [`browserify`](https://browserify.org/) which are often used to make Node.js things available in the browser.

Another possibility is to look at how a module like [`slug`](https://github.com/Trott/slug/blob/main/slug.js) is coded such that it works in the browser and in Node.js, but requires some hacks (and a decent test setup) to do it. For example, it checks `typeof window !== 'undefined'` to switch between code that needs to run in the browser vs. code that needs to run in Node.js. And this bit at the end detects the module system being used and acts accordingly:

```
  if (typeof define !== 'undefined' && define.amd) { // AMD
    define([], function () { return slug })
  } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // CommonJS
    module.exports = slug
  } else { // Script tag
    root.slug = slug
  }
```

Comment: After some searching, it seems that webpack use the same strategy if I make a UMD output? I also found that UMD + ES file output can be used. And mentioning UMD file as "main" and ES file as "module" in package.json will make everything work. I am yet to test it though. I am more directed toward webpack because I am more familiar with it. Is what everything I said correct?

Comment: So I used webpack to generate UMD file, and it is working in node and browser. I think I am going in the right direction now. Thanks.